# How to make Exchange 2003 non-authoritive

Tags: exchange-2003

**Background**

We are a small company with an internally hosted Exchange 2003. It receives email for 2 domains (the company was renamed a few years back). For the sake of argument, the domains are:

- `oldname.com`
- `newname.com`

We have moved `newname.com` to a hosted exchange service, and our DNS record is correctly routing emails. Our internal server still receives email for `oldname.com`, although we have asked our hosting company to accept emails for that domain.

**Problem**

My problem is that emails generated internally from monitoring software, printer, etc. are being caught by our (defunct) internal server and being delivered to the old mailboxes.

I believe that what is happening is that our internal exchange server considers itself to be the authoritive server for `newname.com`. I think it must be looking in active directory for a mailbox and delivering it internally without ever going outside.

**Attempt to fix**

I started to follow the article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321721. I removed the SMTP recipient policy for `newname.com`, and added a dummy address and made it primary. I also answered yes for updating the associated emails. I then restarted the Microsoft Exchange Routing System and SMTP, but emails are still being routed internally.

Is there a way to force the exchange server to route all emails for the domain `newname.com` to the new hosted service?

Answer (score 2):

While there certainly is a way to do this wouldn't the better solution be to reconfigure the devices/software to use your new email provider? You'd need to do this eventually anyway if you plan to decommission the old Exchange server and remove (uninstall) Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your suggestion is reasonable, but the system is older than my time here (I'm not an admin, just the most technical person in a small office). I worry that I might not think of everything that needs to be re-configured, and I hoped that re-configuring exchange would provide a good catch-all.